# Haxe @:generic causes compiler errors?

Tags: generics, attributes, haxe

Below I have a really boiled down program that has a generic class, then makes an instance of it. As the code is written, I get a compile time error "MyGeneric> should be MyGeneric_Int". When I remove the @:generic attributes, it compiles and works fine. Am I misunderstanding the use of @:generic? Is it even needed here? This is on haxe 4.0.5

```
@:generic
class MyGeneric<T>
{
    public function new (fn:T)
    {
        trace(fn);
    }
}

class Repro
{
    static function main()
    {
        var tracer = getTracer();
    }

    public static function getTracer():MyGeneric<Any>
    {
        var arg:Any = 3;
        return getGeneric(arg);
    }

    @:generic
    public static function getGeneric<T>(T):MyGeneric<T>
    {
        return new MyGeneric(T);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this: `return cast getGeneric(arg);`

Comment: While this does work, I have just as much success emitting the @:generic annotation  in the first place. I'm looking for a bit more clarification as to why this occurs, and if it either solution has consequences.